# Is there a limit of how many times I can hit a TVS diode with an overvoltage?

Tags: tvs

I have a system that is powered by 2 batteries that are OR'd together through 2 diodes. They are powering up a speed controller that drives a motor.

Right now, when my motor brakes, I am getting an overvoltage on the input of the speed controller. Normally, my battery will absorb the overvoltage and everything would be great, however, since I started Oring the batteries the path back to batteries is blocked by the diode and I am seeing an overvoltage of 30V on a 50V system so 80V total.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu6v3W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The only thing I can think of is to get a TVS diode and size it correctly to stop any overvoltage, however, the event can happen multiple times at a fast rate. I have not measured it yet, but I suspect that it can happen up to 20Hz. Will a TVS diode be sufficient here? Is there a recovery period for a TVS diode is I guess what I am asking.

The other issue is my system power supplies that are connected on the same node as the motor controller can not handle more than 60V, and I couldn't find a TVS diode that has a working voltage of 50V but a voltage breakdown of anything lower than 60V.

Comment: what are the diodes in front of each battery for?

Comment: @dandavis There is a requirement to not allow the batteries to charge each others. The real circuit actually has a smart diode with fets, however, for simplicity I just put diodes here.

Comment: The limitation will be thermal. Assuming the part is chosen correctly to handle 1strike, the part needs to dissipate the energy (or cool down) before the next threat appears. If the period between threats is too short, the internal temperature will start to staircase before it fails

Comment: TVS is (usually) designed for transient voltages lasting on the order of ns or us. You will typically see power ratings (like 40W or 3kW), and if you look at the datasheets these powers are for very short times, so the actual amount of energy dissipated isnt that big. Depending on the size of your motor, these energy levels may be way smaller than you need

Comment: @JonRB The other part of the question is choosing the correct TVS. From my understanding is a 50V working voltage of a TVS will only clamp at around 80V. It seems like that is too high for my system.

Comment: @BeB00 My pulse was actually closer to 500mS. Though I am not 100% confident on the number as I only took it once before I stopped my test. I do remember that my scope was at 250mS per division and the pulse lasted over 2 divisions.

Comment: TVS diodes do not have an inherent wear out mechanism, unlike MOVs. That doesn't mean you can't degrade them from hitting them too hard. This would be count as misusing them though.

Comment: 250ms is a huge time, and not really suitable for a TVS. What power are you driving your motor at? Maybe you need more elegant power source switching

Comment: @BeB00 I have 4 motors in the system, each are at 50V 20-40A. Depending on the payload.

Comment: "when my motor breaks" did you mean "brakes"? If yes, then your battery is not "absorbing the overvoltage" it is _recuperating_, which is great feature to have. I'd rather replace the pair of batteries with one bigger battery than lose recuperation _and_ create the problem you are trying to resolve here.

Comment: You need to dissipate 4kJ then, which is a massive amount of energy. It's enough to heat up 10g of silicon to >500C. Any reasonable TVS diode would probably melt. Having that energy go into charging batteries is much better than trying to turn it into heat.

Comment: @Maple Yes sorry brakes, Unfortunately, that is not an option. There aren't many 6 cell batteries that have the same energy density as ours 260Wh/KG.

Comment: @BeB00 I was afraid of that. I am wondering if I added a diode that goes back into the batteries and allow for a current path will help? Not sure if that will break my smart diode circuit that is supposed to handle the battery switching.

Comment: Yes, that will mess up your battery switching. Why do you need two packs? You should be able to get one custom pack that has the same characteristics as your two packs

Comment: "to not allow the batteries to charge each others" Do you realize that with your schematics you either have _one_ battery working for two, or both of them working at the _same voltage_, which means they would not "charge each other" even connected directly? Is building 6S2P pack not an option?

Comment: Sounds like you need a braking resistor. This is a high power resistor that turns on when the bus voltage exceeds some threshold. Many VFD's have provision for attaching brake resistors.

Comment: maybe all you need there is a large capacitor.

Comment: @Jasen Someone upthread mentioned 4kJ. That would probably be too much to put in a capacitor. OP should look at the mechanical system kinetic energy and convert it to joules then calculate capacitor size and voltage rise to see if it is workable.

Comment: have the mosfets used as diodes, driven in such as way as to always have one of the batteries connected.